# Pdb files, what does their lines mean?

Tags: c#, debugging, pdb-files

I read a Pdb has the source file names and their lines?

What does "their lines" mean?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: So do you mean the actual source code? I thought there was just a reference to where the files are on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDB file contains information that links the generated machine code back to source file line numbers. This information is used by debuggers to show source debugging.

Comment: So it does not contain the actual source code, that is what I did not understand by "their lines"?

Comment: The PDB file contains line number references, not the actual source code itself.